# subtract each value in column by entire column

Tags: pandas

I have the following `df1` :

```
               prueba
 12-03-2018     7
 08-03-2018     1
 06-03-2018     9
 05-03-2018     5
```

I would like to get each value in the column beggining by the last (`5`) and substract the entire column by that value. then iterate upwards and subtract the remaining values in the column. for each subtraction I would like to generate a column and generate a df with the results of each subtraction:

The desired output would be something like this:

```
             05-03-2018  06-03-2018  08-03-2018  12-03-2018
 12-03-2018     2           -2           6           0
 08-03-2018    -4           -8           0          NaN
 06-03-2018     4            0           NaN        NaN
 05-03-2018     0           NaN          NaN        NaN
```

What I tried to obtain the desired output was, first take `df1` and

```
df2=df1.sort_index(ascending=True)
```

create an empty df:

```
main_df=pd.DataFrame()
```

and then iterate over the values in the column `df2` and subtract to the `df1` column

```
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    datos=df1-row['pruebas']
    df=pd.DataFrame(data=datos,index=index)
    if main_df.empty:
        main_df= df
    else:
        main_df=main_df.join(df)

print(main_df)
```

However the following error outputs:

```
TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, '05-03-2018' was passed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `np.triu`, with array subtract

```
s=df.prueba.values.astype(float)
s=np.triu((s-s[:,None]).T)
s[np.tril_indices(s.shape[0], -1)]=np.nan
pd.DataFrame(s,columns=df.index,index=df.index).reindex(columns=df.index[::-1])
Out[482]: 
            05-03-2018  06-03-2018  08-03-2018  12-03-2018
12-03-2018         2.0        -2.0         6.0         0.0
08-03-2018        -4.0        -8.0         0.0         NaN
06-03-2018         4.0         0.0         NaN         NaN
05-03-2018         0.0         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Kind of messy but does the work:

```
temp = 0
count = 0
df_new = pd.DataFrame()
for i, v, date in zip(df.index, df["prueba"][::-1], df.index[::-1]):
    print(i,v)
    new_val = df["prueba"] - v
    if count > 0:
        new_val[-count:] = np.nan
    df_new[date] = new_val
    temp += v
    count += 1
df_new
```

[image]